# Logical Formulation of the Ending of "Ode on a Grecian Urn" by John Keats

Tags: reference-request, logic

Thanks very much in advance to anyone who can help me on this problem.
Here is the well-known conclusion of "Ode on a Grecian Urn" by John Keats:

"Beauty is truth, truth beauty,"—that is all / Ye know on earth, and all ye need to know.

How would this be expressed in a formula with symbolic logic? There seems to be three statements here: [1] Beauty is truth, truth beauty; [2] that is all ye know on earth; [3] and all ye need to know. Is this correct?

Would the first statement be something like: If B = Beauty, T = Truth, then B = T ˄ T = B, or a similar formulation?

A complication is that the urn is "speaking" to the poet, which accounts for the quotation marks. In different editions, the quotation marks may include only the first statement, the statements in both lines, or express the first statement as a quotation within a quotation. Do these variations affect the logical outcome?

I have searched extensively to see if anyone has approached Keats's assertion formally and I will continue to do so while I work on some sort of solution. There is a Wikipedia article devoted to the poem:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ode_on_a_Grecian_Urn

Again, thanks to everyone for any suggestions.

Comment: I don't see any reason for downvoting this question. MSE is full of answers to trivial questions about how to model natural language in symbolic logic, so why shouldn't we give some help with a non-trivial question of this sort?

Comment: Maybe this needs to be a blog post, to which people can leave their comments. As Q & A, I think it goes against the idea that this part of the website is only math questions and answers with no distractions.

Comment: @Robert Soupe: If the question is along the lines of "how do I formalise X in mathematical language", it is unreasonable to require the asker to phrase the question without extraneous detail (what you call "distractions"). They don't know how to formalise "X" so they don't  know what details are "distractions" from a mathematical point of view.

Comment: @Rob Arthan: That was just my two cents. I think the question is interesting and needs to be somewhere, and I was suggesting the MSE blog for that somewhere. With three re-open votes, that somewhere might turn out to be right here after all.

Answer (score 1):

"Beauty is truth" and "truth [is] beauty" might be formalised in first order logic as an equivalence, $\forall x B(x) \Leftrightarrow T(x)$ ,between two atomic predicates, or (as you suggest) as an equation between two classes, $B = T$. For the rest, you need various kinds of modal logic: some kind of  [epistemic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemic_modal_logic) to model "all you know", together with some kind of [deontic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deontic_modality) to model "all you need to know", and, to model the urn's beliefs, some kind of [doxastic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxastic_logic).

Comment: My apologies if this question was off-topic and I very much appreciate the responses that were made. Might I ask if anyone has any suggestions  about a online forum where I could post this? Thanks.

Comment: I don't  think it is off-topic here, but http://philosophy.stackexchange.com might be a better forum for your question.

Answer (score 1):

"How would this be expressed in a formula with symbolic logic?"

The question betrays a misunderstanding. There is no "right" answer to this sort of question, because the adequacy of a symbolic representation depends entirely on how much logical structure it is appropriate, in the context, to symbolize.

Take a very simple example. Suppose you are given the single claim "Everyone who Mary loves loves Jo". How to symbolise this?

Sometimes, just the unstructured "$P$" is appropriate. [Consider the argument, "If everyone who Mary loves loves Jo, then Jack loves Jo. But everyone who Mary loves does love  Jo. So Jack loves Jo". The logically relevant structure in this case is just "$P \to Q, P \therefore Q$".]

Sometimes, the appropriate representation would be $\forall x(Fx \to Gx)$. [Consider the argument  "Everyone who Mary loves loves Jo. Mary loves Bill. So Bill loves Jo". The logically relevant structure in this case is symbolised "$\forall x(Fx \to Gx), Fb \therefore Gb$".]

Sometimes, the appropriate representation would be something like $\forall x(Lmx \to Lxj)$. And it doesn't stop there. Sometimes we might need to make explicit a domain of discourse as in $(\forall x \in D)(Lmx \to Lxj)$ in order to capture logically relevant features of what is said in the context. And so it goes.

Moral: there is no such thing as the right way of expressing something as a formula from logic. And that applies for Keats quote just as it does for more mundane claims! (That's why exercises in good logic books set things up to make it clear what level of logical detail is expected.)

Comment: The words "right way of expressing something" are yours not the OP's.

Comment: True, but I the presumption seemed to be that there is a context independent answer.